# Disable calling API for a certain condition even if token is valid

Tags: api, security, .net-core, authorization

I have developed an API using .Net core 2.0 with bearer authentication to be called from a mobile application.

One of the requests received by business users is to make some features disabled in case agent did not use/open the application  since a period of time.

For example:
Let's suppose that agent logs in now, a token is generated and will expire in 10 days. But if agent did not use the application for 5 days after logging in, then some features will be disabled even if token is valid.

The problem is that mobile app developers refused to implement the logic behind that. That's why I was thinking about a solution to handle it from my side.

The best I thought about is to:

1. Create an API method **boolean checkAgentValidity** that takes agent ID
2. This method will check if agent ID last call date is < 5 days; if yes then it will update last date = now and returns true, else date won't be updated and returned response is false
3. If response is false, then developers will disable features on the mobile application
4. This method will be called each time the app is opened.

Is it correct that way? Isn't there any other **modern way** based on tokens for example?

Your feedback is more than appreciated!